# Retrieving data from a query in Firebase for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database structure :

```
Users
   user1
      username : username1
      otherdata : otherdata1

   user2
      username : username2
      otherdate : otherdata2
```

What I'm looking for is to display the usernames of my user in a tableview when one user use a uisearchbar on top of the table view. I managed to print the data of each users using this code :`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let strSearch = searchBar.text
    ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: strSearch).queryEnding(atValue: strSearch! + "\u{f8ff}").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for snaps in snapshot.children {
            print(snaps)
        }
    }) { (err) in
        print(err)
    }
}
```

But I'm stuck because I don't know how to retrieve just the username for each user. Can someone tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let strSearch = searchBar.text
        ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: strSearch).queryEnding(atValue: strSearch! + "\u{f8ff}").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var fetchedList = snapshot.value as! [AnyObject]
            for obj in fetchedList { 
            print(obj["username"] as? String) 
            print(obj["otherdata"] as? String) 
       }

        }) { (err) in
            print(err)
        }
    }
```

you will get response like this

```
[{username : username1}, {username : username2}]
```

Comment: actually I didn't say that I had otherdata for each user, I edited my post, and thanks for your answer but I still don't know how to print each username, do I do a loop in the fetchedList , and then I don't know what to do

Comment: Using this will also get other data:
[{username : username1, otherdata : otherdata1}, {username : username2, otherdata : otherdata2}]

Comment: Just try with my answer and see your response.

Comment: yes that what I have, but I'm sorry but l can't figure out how to print the username1 and username2

Comment: for obj in fetchedList {
            print(obj["username"] as? String)
            print(obj["otherdata"] as? String)
        }

Comment: When I trie your code I get this error "Value of optional type 'Any?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" then I fix it by adding ! but I get an other error saying "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

Comment: I copy paste your code but I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'fetchedList'"